# Slack Oauth API redirects to different url if multiple workspace logged in

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am using slack oauth api and has url like 
https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL&team=TEAM_ID&scope=identify%20client&state=unused
It works fine but if i have any other slack workspace say abc opened in the same browser it redirects to
https://abc.slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL&team=TEAM_ID&scope=identify%20client&state=unused
and return error OAuth Error: invalid_team_for_non_distributed_app

Answer (score 1):

You must go into slack settings go to Manage Distribution and enable public distribution